# Require form submit before viewing page - rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form that I would like to require people to submit before they can view another page.  However, this shouldn't require a sign in or user authentication.  Is there any way around this? Essentially, I would like to prevent users from being able to skip to the content using the url.

I was considering adding a Jquery modal onto the f.submit action? Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use a session variable to determine whether user had visited the first page and redirect them from the other url if they haven't. Actually you don't even need to redirect, just load the contents of the page you want them to see first.

Comment: I need to have people enter their names and emails before they can view a page which is controlled by users. The client has requested that they not have to sign up for an account but have access to view the page with the requirement that they log their name and email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send back the page as the http response to the http POST when a user submits the form (don't have your server respond to http GET to serve that page). That way, you first collect the form's informations and then send respond with the page.

Create a POST route in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
post 'form', to: 'form#create'
```

In your controller, save the form data you're interested in and respond with the page:

```
def create
  #save the form data in a Form model?
  @form = Form.new form_params
  if @form.save
    render :page
  else
    redirect_to :new
  end
end
```

You'll need to adapt the above code to fit your needs.

Comment: This sounds like it would work, could you point me in the right direction of where to look to get started on this?